# Displaying a progress dialog with osascript - why is this sample from Apple not showing a dialog?

Tags: macos, applescript, macos-big-sur, osascript

I think I've read just about every question here on applescript dialogs with progress bars and I'm still not getting something.

Specifically [this sample from Apple](https://developer.apple.com/library/archive/documentation/LanguagesUtilities/Conceptual/MacAutomationScriptingGuide/DisplayProgress.html), I have copied the code and compiled to a `test.scr` and when I run it with `osascript test.scr` I never see a dialog.

I'm showing the sample code from that link here for your reference:

```
set theImages to choose file with prompt "Please select some images to process:" of type {"public.image"} with multiple selections allowed
 
-- Update the initial progress information
set theImageCount to length of theImages
set progress total steps to theImageCount
set progress completed steps to 0
set progress description to "Processing Images..."
set progress additional description to "Preparing to process."
 
repeat with a from 1 to length of theImages
 
    -- Update the progress detail
    set progress additional description to "Processing image " & a & " of " & theImageCount
 
    -- Process the image
 
    -- Increment the progress
    set progress completed steps to a
 
    -- Pause for demonstration purposes, so progress can be seen
    delay 1
end repeat
 
-- Reset the progress information
set progress total steps to 0
set progress completed steps to 0
set progress description to ""
set progress additional description to ""
```

Similar behavior from other samples I've seen here on stack. No dialog ever shows.

I am expecting to see this dialog

[image]

I'm on Big Sur 11.5.

Comment: Works for me.  Note that the progress is shown differently when running in the Script Editor vs an application.

Comment: @red_menace...hmm. You're running it via `osascript` from the command line? Are you on Big Sur?

Comment: I think, this is impossible, because **osascript** is shell command which can't be interrupted like applications in the middle of process, update some dialog's state, then continue.

Comment: How the progress is displayed depends on where the script is run from (editor, application, scripts menu).  The script runs, but `osascript` doesn’t provide any context for showing it.

Comment: Hmm. In truth what I'm trying to do is run a bash script that does work and I want to fork off a progress dialog while it's working. Maybe this just isn't possible. I thought I could call `osascript mything.scr &`

Comment: No, the problem is the shell command doesn't have main loop for interrupting processes like applications.